# Why does bond price go up with interest rate decrease?

Tags: bonds, interest-rate, inflation

I understand that a decrease in prevailing market interest rate causes a downward pressure on the bond yield and, equivalently, an upward pressure on the bond price. But what if a decrease in interest rate leads the investors to anticipate inflation? Wouldn't the anticipation of inflation cause the bond to be worth less and subsequently exert a downward pressure on the bond price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The price of a bond is tied to the interest rate (yield) *of that bond* by a simple formula, so the effect of one on the other is fully predictable. The relation between prices and/or yields *of different bonds* -- e.g., with different maturities or credit risks -- is much more complex and can involve secondary effects of the kind you mention. These are measured by yield *curves* and yield *spreads*.

If the "prevailing market interest rate" you refer to is a short-term rate like the Federal Funds Rate, then indeed it can happen that a rate cut leads to an *increase* in long-term bond yields (steepening the yield curve) due to inflation expectations. Or vice versa, short-term rate hikes may not increase long-term rates (the yield curve may flatten) -- this was Alan Greenspan's famous [conundrum](https://www.financialsense.com/contributors/matthew-kerkhoff/greenspan-s-conundrum) in the mid-2000s.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I guess the standard explanations such as follows over-simplify the matter: https://www.wellsfargofunds.com/ind/investing-basics-and-planning/bonds-and-interest-rates.html

Answer (score 0):

If rates are increasing and bond prices are declining,  that makes older bonds less attractive because newer bonds offer a higher rate. In order to be competitive, the price of the older bonds must decline otherwise no one would buy them. Conversely, if rates are declining, investors/traders  are wiling to pay more for the older bonds because they offer a higher yield than current bonds.

This process happens as rates change as well as when investors/traders anticipate that rates are going to change.

Answer (score 0):

Bonds are sold ('offered') with a defined interest rate, which doesn't change afterwards.
Imagine you bought a 1000$ - 3% bond, and the market interest goes down below that - your bond is suddenly better than other investments on the market, so demand goes up, and people pay you more than the 1000$ to have it. On the other hand, if market interest goes up, over the 3%, your bond is now a poor investment, as you could get more than 3% on the market - so people won't pay you the full 1000$ for the bond.

As the current market interest rate and your bond's info are known, offer and demand adjust your bond's price perfectly so that a buyer of your bond makes exactly the market interest rate - not more and not less.